# One-time binding along with directive's bidirectional binding and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Say we have the following directive:

```
app.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { prop: '=' },
    template: '<h1>{{prop}}</h1>'
  };
});
```

Angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#how-to-benefit-from-one-time-binding) says it's possible to use an one-time binding along with a bidirectional binding, like this:

```
<foo prop="::someProperty"></foo>
```

And it works; if `someProperty` later changes, the `foo` directive won't know about it.

Now consider this markup:

```
<foo ng-repeat="item in items" prop="::item"></foo>
```

In this case, if `item` later changes, `foo` will be notified, as if there's a regular binding in place. The `::` doesn't seem to have any practical effect (it does prevent an extra watch from being created, I checked myself). I created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SYEyxQduBeG9DyriT1i6) that illustrates both cases.

My question is: is that behavior correct? I would expect it to be consistent in both scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is yes, this is the correct behavior. When an `item` within `items` changes, a new instance of the template is created while the old is simply removed. In your case, a new `foo` element is created and therefore, the `prop` attribute value is also new. This is from the Angular [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) documentation:

> When the contents of the collection change, ngRepeat makes the corresponding changes to the DOM:
>
> - When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the DOM.
> - When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from the DOM.
> - When items are reordered, their respective templates are reordered in the DOM.

It doesn't explicitly state what happens on update. But, I believe the new replaces the old rather than update.

Comment: You're dead on, sir. I've just confirmed that by using this [little snippet](https://gist.github.com/mbenford/daee660193ff42077357). `ngRepeat` removes the current element and adds a new one when the item itself is updated.